# PHP Post and visit page

Tags: post, curl, pecl

I need to POST data to a payment terminal with PHP, but instead of returning the data like `curl_exec()` does, it actually needs to visit the page..

This is what I came up with.

```
<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body onload="document.frm1.submit()">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $connectorUrl ?>" name="frm1">
                <input type="hidden" name="Data" value="<?php echo $data ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="InterfaceVersion" value="<?php echo $interfaceVersion ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="Seal" value="<?php echo $seal ?>">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But later on I realised there might be that one person that has JS disabled and it wont work.. so I found this:

```
$values = [
            'Data' => $data,
            'interfaceVersion' => $interfaceVersion,
            'Seal' => $seal
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $connectorUrl);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $values);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        $returned = curl_exec( $ch );
```

But this won't actually visit the page, this is more like an AJAX request.

Does anybody know how to POST and visit a page using PHP only? Or are the 1% non-JS clients screwed?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I surmise you are attempting to send the user to a different page

Comment: Correct, same as a normal POST form, where the user is sent to the action page with the POST info. But without the actual form. I need this for a payment portal and I want to make sure that even the one procent of people with JS disabled can properly pay.